# Выборка данных по кругу

Tags: sqlite3

Таблица:

```
id
1
2
3
4
```

Нужно выбрать 3 следующих значения от заданного:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = 1
```

Результат: 2,3,4

Если же данных получается меньше требумых трёх, то брать остальные элементы с начала таблицы:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = 3
```

Результат: 4,1,2

Comment: не совсем понятно , что значит "выбрать 3 значения от заданного".

Comment: Судя по вашему примеру выходит, что вы хотите выбрать все значения _кроме_ заданного

Comment: пример: я на странице сайта с id = 3, мне нужно чтобы в выборке было id следующих за за ней страниц (хоть 5 не важно) по порядку. один момент чтобы както это зациклить

Comment: Судя по вашему примеру выходит, что вы хотите выбрать все значения кроме заданного === нет не все, нужное количество например 3

Comment: "нет не все" - Дополните ваши примеры соответствующими данными.

Comment: есть 100 страниц, нужно организовать перелинковку находимся на странице с id 15 значит нужно получить следующих по значению 5 страниц (или 10 неважно это значение берется в конфиге) , если нам брать нечего например мы делаем запрос находясь на последней странице с id 100 или 99 нужно взять id с начала 1,2 и т.д сколько нужно, то есть зациклить этот процесс

Comment: `SELECT \`id\` FROM \`table\` WHERE \`id\` != 1 LIMIT 3` Вам это нужно?

Comment: naym  нет! чуть выше описал проблему, с каждой страницы результаты запроса будут разные, а вашем примере он будет постоянным, мне нужно смещение от нужного мне id + зациклить

Comment: @naym, см. мой ответ. Возможно, накосячил в нём, но идея такая, насколько я понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, здесь подзапрос **b** берёт данные с начала таблицы, если их будет не хватать в основном запросе **a** при заданном лимите, тем самым, организуя "зацикленность"

```
with a as (select id from table where id > 5 limit 3), 
     b as (select id from table limit (select 3-count(*) from a)) 
select a.id from a union select b.id from b;
```

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо большое!

Comment: в версиях ниже sqlite 3.8 "with" не работает, подскажите можно как то адаптировать под sqlite 3.7?

Answer (score 1):

Приблизительно так:

```
select top 3 id from (
  select top 3 id from table where id > @id order by id
  union all
  select top 3 id from table where id < @id order by id
);
```

Comment: наверное, во втором запросе все же стоит писать `<` вместо `!=`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, согласен, а то дубликаты получатся, если записей меньше трёх.